# how do I tell the php to go into the next directory?

Tags: php

I'm stuck with some simple code.

I have created a database query that successfully makes '$albumPath' correctly point to the url 'albums/album0147'

How do I format the link to include another directory ie. 'albums/album0147/imageThumbs'

```
echo $albumPath;
```

displays albums/album0147 correctly on the page, but what do I put after $albumpath to correctly display albums/album0147/imageThumbs ?

I'm new to this, but learning rapidly through trial and error.

Comment: `echo $albumPath . "/imageThumbs";` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$albumPath` is just a string, you can use [the `.` operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) to concatenate strings:

```
$albumPathImgs = $albumPath."/imageThumbs";
```

If `"imageThumbs"` is stored in another variable, say `$thumbsDir`:

```
$thumbsDir = "imageThumbs";
$albumPathImgs = $albumPath."/".$thumbsDir;
echo $albumsPathImgs;
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked (I knew it would be simple, I was missing out the full stop/period)

Comment: @halli123 Remember to accept the answer that best answers your question, so that others who come to this question can see what the best solution is.

Comment: It wouldn't let me for "6 minutes" when I clicked it. Done now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define the slash independently so you can name your albums and files based on It's name only:

```
$slash = '/';
```

So you can define your main album:

```
$albums = 'albums';
```

Then you can define your sub albums:

```
$album0147 = 'album0147';
$imageThumbs = 'imageThumbs';
```

Now you can concatenate the albums together and make the url valid by adding the forwardslash in between (or a backward one, depending on your OS):

```
$url = $albums. $slash. $album0147. $slash. $imageThumbs;
```

You can even go so far as to define the image names:

```
$img1 = 'img101.png';

$image = $url. $img1;
```